# PowerShell Get All Files in Folder Tree LastAccessed and export to csv

Tags: powershell, file, properties-file

I have a Powershell Script that I am using to try to Get ALL Files in a Folder Tree that were LastAccessedTime > 365 days ago. I know my script is using Plus 10 days - but that is for testing purposes as I have just created files to test this with.

```
$Folder = 'D:\Temp\*.*'
$lastAccessDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(10)

Get-ChildItem $Folder -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.LastAccessTime -lt $lastAccessDate
} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name, LastAccessTime | 
 Export-CSV "C:\Temp\FileListing.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

I have Also tried this code based on this link [Learn PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.3)

```
Get-ChildItem $Folder -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.LastAccessTime -lt $lastAccessDate
} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Expand - Property Name, LastAccessTime | 
 Export-CSV "C:\Temp\FileListing.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Error on the first code

```
Select-Object : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required 
by parameter 'ExpandProperty'. Specified method is not supported.
```

Error on this

```
Get-ChildItem $Folder -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.LastAccessTime -lt $lastAccessDate
} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name,LastAccessTime | 
 Export-CSV "C:\Temp\FileListing.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
Select-Object : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ExpandProperty'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:8 char:35
+ } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name,LastAccessTime |
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
```

Comment: Looks good to me, what's the issue? `(Get-Date).AddDays(-365)` instead of  `(Get-Date).AddDays(10)`, or `(Get-Date).AddYears(-1)`, depending on how you want to handle leap years.

Comment: @ErikBlomgren - as mentioned I am using AddDays(10) because I just created the files in my testing folder. The error Select-Object : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ExpandProperty'. Specified method is not supported.

Comment: You can only expand one property with `-ExpandProperty`

Comment: @Ken, you'll want to use `-Property`, not `-ExpandProperty`. Name cannot be expanded since it's a string, not an object. `Select-Object -Property` selects the mentioned properrty of the object(s) on the thing comming down the pipe, `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` selects the object of the object comming down the pipe and shows the properties of that objects objects.

Comment: @ErikBlomgren but isn't the file object 'Select-Object' the object that I am expanding properties on ? 
However in using property the thing works! Wow.. If you write a quick answer I will select as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove `Expand` from your code, like so:

```
$Folder = 'D:\Temp\*.*'
$lastAccessDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(10)

Get-ChildItem $Folder -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.LastAccessTime -lt $lastAccessDate
} | Select-Object -Property Name, LastAccessTime | 
 Export-CSV "C:\Temp\FileListing.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

The first error says that `Name` cannot be expanded since it's a string, not an object that contains properties. `Select-Object -Property` selects the given properties of the object(s) comming down the pipe, `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` selects the *properties of the given objects of the object(s)* comming down the pipe.